# Перегрузка метода анонимного класса в Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Есть интерфейс IFoo (у него куча методов, в том числе какой-то bar), есть класс Foo который реализует этот интерфейс.

Где-то есть метод accept, который на вход принимает IFoo.

Я хочу передать в этот метод экземпляр класса Foo с перегруженным одним методом bar(). То есть я не хочу создавать где-то отдельный класс-наследник от Foo в отдельном классе. А хочу прямо здесь в вызове accept создать экземпляр и перезагрузить.

Я просто не соображу, как это физически сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот ваш пример:

```
interface IFoo {
  fun bar()
}

open class Foo: IFoo {
  override fun bar() {
    println("Foo")
  }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  accept(object: Foo() {
    override fun bar() {
        super.bar()
        println("Anonymous")
    }
  })
}

fun accept(foo: IFoo) {
  foo.bar()
}
```

Output:

> Foo
>   Anonymous

А вот документация
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html